# How do you deal with different language web application and Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

The web site that I am testing enables the user to choose a language. And if the language is switched from English to some else language, all the label names of the drop down menus are now different.

So i work around this by always switching to English in the beginning of the test, this way:

open | /&UIlanguage=EN

but I do not like this workaround because i don't find it sophisticated enough and it feels like cheating.

I am new to Selenium IDE and im sure there are better ways.

With XPATH i use "OR" expressions, but can i use OR expressions when not using XPATH?

For example

type | id=orderbillingcity | label=Ruse <> label=Русе

how can i do that?

Comment: Hey buddy you can try xpath or css for locating the element on webpage as they will not be dependent if web page converted into different language (localization)

Comment: how do i get the xpath of a drop down menu options? i try using xpath but when i click on the drop down it gives me the drop down menu xpath, not allowing me to choose one of the options and get its xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use "XPATH" or "CSS" or "ID" locator to perform localization checks. languages or text does not make any impact on these locators. this will always remains same.
- but if we use "LINK" or "NAME" locator then it will always change according to your language. so do not use "link" or "name" locator to perform localization checks.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but how do i determine which is the xpath of a dynamically changing number of select options in a drop down menu?

Comment: you can use "xpath: position" locator for drop down menu (select from TARGET option of IDE). e.g `//div/div/a[3]` in this "//div/div" is xpath of your drop down & "/a[3]" is your option from that drop down. you can change the number which is present in "[ ]" according to your size of drop down list.